# How to update a row from another uncompleted row

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

Assume I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id UUID,
  field_1 VARCHAR
  field_2 VARCHAR
  field_3 VARCHAR
);
```

This table is linked to a form in front-end where I can update field_1, field_2 and field_3, but I want to only update the fields that the user has filled.

For software and team reasons, we have the following function to update, built and called from front-end:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_my_table(
  _my_table_input my_table%ROWTYPE
) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
   UPDATE 
       my_table
   SET 
       field_1 = _my_table_input.field_1
       field_2 = _my_table_input.field_2,
       field_3 = _my_table_input.field_3
   WHERE
       id = _my_table.id
END;
```

`_my_table_input` represents a row of table with an id and a list of all fields that the user has modified.

In the code I'm treating, the issue I'm facing is that I'm passing a table row which can be incomplete, meaning that for instance `_my_table_input.field_3` can be null, and in this case, I don't want to update `field_3`

I could change the way the front works, but I was thinking and I'm looking for an elegant to UPDATE my data of only defined fields of the function input, something like:

```
UPDATE 
   my_table
SET 
   field_1 = _my_table_input.field_1 IF EXISTS(_my_table_input.field_1)
   field_2 = _my_table_input.field_2 IF EXISTS(_my_table_input.field_2),
   field_3 = _my_table_input.field_3 IF EXISTS(_my_table_input.field_3)
WHERE
   id = _my_table.id
```

I checked online, and on PostgreSQL docs, but I could not find what I want. So I thought maybe some of you could have a brilliant idea.

Comment: What about `coalesce(_my_table_input.field1, field1)`? This assumes you will never explicitly use `NULL` as an input value.

Comment: I thought about it, could work actually in my case, but i was wondering if there would be another solution if at some point `NULL` is passed as an input value. In this case, i would want to update `field1` with null.

Comment: With the current data content your above 'another solution' does not exist. The issue is you have 2 totally differently different condition giving a NULL input. 1. Field is incomplete so do not update. 2. User want updated to NULL so update. The problem being that at present there is no way to determine the proper course of action. Just go ahead with the coalesce solution. Do not be overly worried about "*what might happen at some point*".   That falls into the realm of normal system maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

How about using "dynamic query" approach?

I'd like to share the idea, although I probably don't know the most graceful way to do so with Postgreql, but I think it may go like these:

```
with 
-- combining each desired field in temp table
set_fields (field) as ( 
    values 
        (case 
            when _my_table_input.field1 is not null 
            then concat('field1 = ', _my_table_input.field1)
            else null 
        end),
        (case 
            when _my_table_input.field2 is not null 
            then concat('field2 = ', _my_table_input.field2)
            else null 
        end),
),
-- aggregating parts of statement in another temp table
update_sql_statement as (
    select 
        concat(
            'update ',
            'my_table ',
            'set ',
            array_to_string(array_agg(field), ', ')
            -- ' where id = _my_table.id'
        ) as statement
    from set_fields
)

-- Then take the finally runable statment string out to execute
-- This is the part I'm not sure about, but I believe postgresql have some way of executing certain string from temp.

-- execute(format(select statement from update_sql_statement))
select statement from update_sql_statement
```

Try see [this doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ecpg-dynamic.html) if it help spark something.